# Need help in writing query for loop in oracle XML column

Tags: oracle

i have the below XML data in one column:

```
<Employee_part part_id="A" part_name="ABC" >    

  <Employee_scoring_information >
    <keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="1">
      <integer_key value="2"/>
    </keyset>
  </Employee_scoring_information>
</Employee_part>
<Employee_part part_id="B" part_name="BCD" >

  <Employee_scoring_information >
    <match_keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="3">
    <integer_key value="2"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="4" source_key_id="1"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="1" source_key_id="2"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="2" source_key_id="3"/>
    </match_keyset>
    <match_keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="3">
      <source_key correct_target_id="5" source_key_id="1"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="1" source_key_id="2"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="2" source_key_id="3"/>
    </match_keyset>

  </Employee_scoring_information>
</Employee_part>
<Employee_part part_id="C" part_name="CDE" >

  <Employee_scoring_information >
    <keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="2">
      <integer_key value="1"/>
      <integer_key value="2"/>
    </keyset>
  </Employee_scoring_information>
</Employee_part>
```

the XML is having three parts (Employee_part part_id="A","B","C") Part A has **keyset**, Part B has **match_keyset**, Part c Has **keyset**. when it has keyset then i need to pull data from integer_key/@Value (Ex:2), when it has match_keyset i need to pull data from source_key correct_target_id, source_key_id in the format of (Ex: 1/4,2/1,3/2; 1/5,2/1,3/2;). each part is separtaed by Pipe (|) symbol.

i am trying to write the below query to display the following output:
2 | 1/4,2/1,3/2; 1/5,2/1,3/2; | 1,2

```
SELECT CASE EXISTSNODE (EMP_CNTNT_XML,
                        '/Employee/Employee_content/Employee_part')
          WHEN 1
          THEN
             RTRIM (
                REPLACE (
                   REPLACE (
                      CAST (
                         XMLQUERY (
                            '
for $i in //Employee_part/@part_id return 
concat
( 
concat
(
xs:string
(
for $x in //Employee_part where $x/@part_id = $i return 
for $y in $x//integer_key/@value return 
concat
(
xs:string($y)
,","
)
)
,


xs:string
(
for $k in //Employee_part where $k/@part_id = $i return  
concat(                                 
xs:string(
for $x in $k/@source_key_id return 
for $y in $k/@correct_target_id return                                       
concat(xs:string($x), "/", xs:string($y), "" ) )
,",")                     

)

)
,
"|"
) 
'
                            PASSING EMP_CNTNT_XML RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2 (1000)),
                      ' ',
                      ''),
                   ',|',
                   '|'),
                '|')
       END
          AS XML_DATA
  FROM Employee
 WHERE emp_no = 'SCH1234';
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be to change the XML into relational data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE emp AS
SELECT XMLTYPE('<Employee><Employee_content>
<Employee_part part_id="A" part_name="ABC" >    

  <Employee_scoring_information >
    <keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="1">
      <integer_key value="2"/>
    </keyset>
  </Employee_scoring_information>
</Employee_part>
<Employee_part part_id="B" part_name="BCD" >

  <Employee_scoring_information >
    <match_keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="3">
    <integer_key value="2"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="4" source_key_id="1"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="1" source_key_id="2"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="2" source_key_id="3"/>
    </match_keyset>
    <match_keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="3">
      <source_key correct_target_id="5" source_key_id="1"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="1" source_key_id="2"/>
      <source_key correct_target_id="2" source_key_id="3"/>
    </match_keyset>

  </Employee_scoring_information>
</Employee_part>
<Employee_part part_id="C" part_name="CDE" >

  <Employee_scoring_information >
    <keyset keyset_weight="1" number_of_keyset_members="2">
      <integer_key value="1"/>
      <integer_key value="2"/>
    </keyset>
  </Employee_scoring_information>
</Employee_part>
</Employee_content></Employee>') AS Employee_part
FROM dual;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_SCORING_INFORMATION AS 
SELECT part_id, part_name, SCORING_INFORMATION
FROM EMP e
    CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/Employee/Employee_content/Employee_part' PASSING EMPLOYEE_PART COLUMNS
        part_id VARCHAR2(10) PATH '@part_id',
        part_name VARCHAR2(10) PATH '@part_name',
        SCORING_INFORMATION XMLTYPE PATH 'Employee_scoring_information'
        ) p;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_MATCH_KEYSET AS 
SELECT part_id, part_name, keyset_weight, number_of_keyset_members, keyset_NO, keyset
FROM EMP_SCORING_INFORMATION e
    CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/Employee_scoring_information/match_keyset' PASSING SCORING_INFORMATION COLUMNS
        keyset_weight INTEGER PATH '@keyset_weight',
        number_of_keyset_members INTEGER PATH '@number_of_keyset_members',
        keyset_NO FOR ORDINALITY,
        keyset XMLTYPE PATH '/'
    ) p;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_KEYSET AS 
SELECT part_id, part_name, keyset_weight, number_of_keyset_members, keyset_NO, keyset
FROM EMP_SCORING_INFORMATION e
    CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/Employee_scoring_information/keyset' PASSING SCORING_INFORMATION COLUMNS
        keyset_weight INTEGER PATH '@keyset_weight',
        number_of_keyset_members INTEGER PATH '@number_of_keyset_members',
        keyset_NO FOR ORDINALITY,
        keyset XMLTYPE PATH '/'
    ) p;    

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_MATCH_KEYSET_source_key AS 
SELECT keyset_NO, part_id, part_name, keyset_weight, number_of_keyset_members,
    key_NO, correct_target_id, source_key_id
FROM EMP_MATCH_KEYSET e
    CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/match_keyset/source_key' PASSING keyset COLUMNS
        correct_target_id INTEGER PATH '@correct_target_id',
        source_key_id INTEGER PATH '@source_key_id',
        key_NO FOR ORDINALITY
    )p;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_MATCH_KEYSET_INTEGER_KEY AS 
SELECT keyset_NO, part_id, part_name, keyset_weight, number_of_keyset_members,
    key_NO, integer_key
FROM EMP_MATCH_KEYSET e
    CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/match_keyset/integer_key' PASSING keyset COLUMNS
        integer_key INTEGER PATH '@value',
        key_NO FOR ORDINALITY
    )p;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMP_KEYSET_INTEGER_KEY AS 
SELECT keyset_NO, part_id, part_name, keyset_weight, number_of_keyset_members,
    key_NO, integer_key
FROM EMP_KEYSET e
    CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/keyset/integer_key' PASSING keyset COLUMNS
        integer_key INTEGER PATH '@value',
        key_NO FOR ORDINALITY
    )p;
```

I don't fully understand your requirements but as starting point you can use this query:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT LISTAGG(SOURCE_KEY_ID||'/'||CORRECT_TARGET_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY key_NO) AS KEY_ID, keyset_NO
    FROM EMP_MATCH_KEYSET_SOURCE_KEY
    GROUP BY keyset_NO)
SELECT LISTAGG(KEY_ID, '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY keyset_NO)
FROM t;

1/4,2/1,3/2; 1/5,2/1,3/2
```

With rather simple JOIN, UNION and/or CASE you should be able to get desired output.

Comment: I am trying to display the output  like this Part A (integer Key Value) | Part B Values (if it has match keyset i need to display source_key_id/target_key_id) | Part C Integer key value. Ex: 2 | 1/4,2/1,3/2; 1/5,2/1,3/2; | 1,2 . parts are not static , it can have n number of parts. the only logic is if XML has match keysets then i need to display source_key/Target_key ,for keysets just display integer_key value.

Comment: i got it  with one more for loop (match_key_set)resolved.. Thank you .